# how to create this shape with only divs and css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

> [image: the shape you need to create using only divs and CSS]

I have this shape as a PNG that I would like to create it with CSS so that I can dynamically change the fill color.

My question is: How can I most effectively recreate this image using only `div`s and CSS?

Note that there is a 5px white stroke around the orange fill. That stroke needs to be created as well. And the area to the right of the curve on the right needs to be transparent. Your CSS can not use external assets such as background images.

Ideally the CSS would work in the majority of browsers including IE 7, 8 and 9. But that's not absolutely required.

Go forth you CSS wizards and show me your darkest dirtiest CSS secrets. I will be putting a bounty of 50 on this as soon as the site allows me, and will award that fully to the best answer, regardless of when you submit you answer.

Let's see what you've got.

Comment: try to look at SVG and PATH : http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp

Comment: @Alex Peta please, don't link to that site: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @Alex Peta Not needed in this case

Comment: @Simon Lehmann Wow, you taught me something about w3schools. I had no idea. Thanks for the link.

Comment: You cant do a round shape in ie7-8
Unless you use pictures so you could do "jacktheripper" example for the new browsers and then use a <!--[if lte IE8]> and use a picture instead here

Answer (score 33):

**HTML**

```
<div id="css"></div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#css {
  width: 118px;
  height: 74px;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  background: red;
  border: 6px solid white;
  border-radius: 20% / 62%;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px; 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; 
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/h7jYG/23/)

I dare you to guess which one is which without looking at the HTML ;)

Comment: +1 as you were the first to address the note about the 5px white stroke around it.

Comment: pretty close. I get a bit of black coming through on the ends of the arc in FF.

Comment: @Rafe--seems to be partially based off the numbers chosen. If I change the `18%` to `20%` for me Firefox renders it better, so it may be a factor of picking just the right number for your application.

Answer (score 5):

This version is also compatible with IE9...

HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />​
<div id="image">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#image{
background:orange;
 border: 5px solid white;
-moz-border-radius: 20% / 60%;
-webkit-border-radius: 20% / 60%;
border-radius: 20% / 60%;
-moz-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
height:100px;
width:150px;   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

just put the correct color, eventually change the dimensions

```
#shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
  border: 5px solid white;
  border-radius: 15% / 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: `position`, `margin`, `text-align`, `text-indent` and `color` don't affect the shape at all. `border-color` would be nice to add though.